# C++ RTSP video capture implementation

Tags: c++, sockets, video, rtsp

I would like to develop a very tiny and small RTSP client to get the video stream from network cameras. Does anybody know where can I find a simple explanation of the protocol and some good examples?

Best regards,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You connect to the camera via RTSP protocol to query its capabilities, identify streams and prepare/start transmission.

- [RFC 2326 - Real Time Streaming Protocol (RTSP)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2326.txt)

As a part of initialization and handshaking, you will discover available streams.

- [RFC 4566 - SDP Session Description Protocol](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4566.txt)

Then you will set up RTP session(s) to receive data, over UDP or sharing the same TCP connection.

- [RFC 3550 - RTP A Transport Protocol for Real-Time Applications](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3550.txt)
- [RFC 4571 - Framing Real-time Transport Protocol (RTP) and RTP Control Protocol (RTCP) Packets over Connection-Oriented Trans](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4571.txt)

To decode media streams you will convert the payload into pure data you need for further processing. With IP cameras your primary interest is perhaps MPEG-4 AVC (H.264):

- [RFC 3984 - RTP Payload Format for H.264 Video](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3984.txt)
- [RFC 6184 - RTP Payload Format for H.264 Video](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6184.txt)

This looks like some (introductory) reading.

Answer (score 3):

Try [GStreammer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) library. It is modular, wery flexible library, which can be used for streamming (both client and server). Just check the docs and pick right plugins.

GStreammer could be used in two ways: as a commandline tool or as a library in your project, depending on your requirements.