# Play FLV data synchronously

Tags: c#, .net, media-player, rtmp

I am just investigating http://www.broccoliproducts.com/softnotebook/rtmpclient/rtmpclient.php RTMP client code. And it is working fine so it gets data and saves the FLV file locally.

The [**code**](http://www.broccoliproducts.com/softnotebook/rtmpclient/Red5Download.cs) is pretty simple. So my questions are:

**1. Is it possible to play this streaming synchronously? (okay with some delay because of the caching)
(I've tried to open writing file via VLC but it is busy...)**

**2. Any clue how to implement it?**

**!!! It is not any kind of advertisement of this project! I just need to create some RTMP Player in WPF.**

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027062/c-rtsp-video-capture-implementation/13028013#13028013

Comment: You mean how to playback the stream instead of downloading? What do you mean by synchronously? Playback a live stream?

Comment: @OnurYILDIRIM yes yes. Dont save it into the file but instead of it playback at the screen.

Comment: An `.flv` is still considered a `.swf` essentially correct? If thats true you use `Com Objects`?  If you confirm that my above remark is true I'll write out a simple solution.

Comment: @Greg Well if it is possible to Play it somehow using rtmp streaming yes pls.

Comment: What are your requirements; just C#?  Or you trying to utilize ASP.NET, WinForm, WPF, Javascript?  What other requirements are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic post until you provide some additional requirements.

Inside of Flash you'd create a button, then implement the following `ActionScript`.

```
on (press) {
    fscommand("Variable1", "Variable2");
}
```

Then inside of Visual Studio you need to add the `COM Object` reference for `Shockwave Flash Object`.  You'll need to ensure that you `embed` is set to true.

Now inside Visual Studio you should be able to go to `Properties` and find `fscommand` which will allow you to physically connect the value from the Flash Movie.

`AxShockwaveFlashObjects._IShockwaveFlashEvents_FSCommandEvent`

That will collect your variables inside of Flash.  You'd simply use `e.command` and `e.arg` for example to have the collected item to do something.  Such as...

```
lbl_Result.Text="The " + e.args.ToString() + " " + e.command.ToString()+ " was clicked.";
```

And boom your now transmitting your Flash movie's data from Flash into Visual Studio.  That is quite simple, quite straight forward.

This will allow your C# application to actually inherit and utilize your Flash Video.

*Things to Consider:*

- Make sure that you've set `embed` to true.  That is what will physically hold all the `Path References` within your Flash Object.  Otherwise it may call an invalid path.

*Additional Help for Reference:*

1. Inside your project open `Solution Explorer`.
2. Right Click on `Reference` and `Add Reference`.
3. Go to `COM Object`.

> These are the objects available:

- `Shockwave ActiveX`
- `Flash Accessibility`
- `Flash Broker`
- `Shockwave Flash`

The above solution will let you actually use Flash within it's native environment your just simply passing variable data or controls you'd like implemented into C# this way.  This way you can actually use RTMP straight to Flash. Your C# application will just expose the Flash Object.

That is a generic approach, when you provide some extra information I'll update to try and assist you better. There are also libraries such F-In-The-Box, LibRTMP, which may also help.

The above is quite Generic like I stated; but it will invoke whatever quality you noted in your Flash Video Object; then your C# can simply adjust them like:

```
<% MyYoutubeUtils.ShowEmebddedVideo("<object width="425" height="344"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/gtNlQodFMi8&hl=en&fs=1"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/gtNlQodFMi8&hl=en&fs=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" width="425" height="344"></embed></object>") %>
```

Or...

```
public static string ShowEmbeddedVideo(string youtubeObject)
{
    var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(youtubeObject);
    var returnObject = string.Format("<object type=\"{0}\" data=\{1}\"><param name=\"movie\" value=\"{1}\" />",
        xdoc.Root.Element("embed").Attribute("type").Value,
        xdoc.Root.Element("embed").Attribute("src").Value);
    return returnObject;
}
```

Which you can find the thread here: [Additional Embed Instructions and Details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547101/purify-embedding-youtube-videos-method-in-c-sharp)

That is how you could put your Flash into C#, there are ways to also output your C# to Actionscript.  But without more details on what your trying to do I can't really do more then these generic responses.

Please keep in mind, this is on the assumption your trying to store the `FLV` within your applications, or aggregate data from C# to Flash.  I'll need more detail to assist further. I'm not quite sure why C# is required and what your trying to actually do.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Cygwin you could pipe output through `tee`

```sh
rtmpdump -i "rtmp://server/app playpath=mp4:foo.mp4" | tee a.flv | vlc -
```

This will save the output to a file, while simultaneously playing the stream through VLC. If you prefer not to install Cygwin I have
[**a small version**](http://code.google.com/p/strm/downloads) available, only 3.2 MB. Also you could probably just find a Windows version of `tee`.

Comment: Well.. Thank you! But I need C# solution.

Answer (score 1):

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) can play back most any source and has bindings for many languages. .net is certainly on the list.

One source: [sample](http://libvlcnet.codeplex.com/)
Some more info: [here](http://wiki.videolan.org/.Net_Interface_to_VLC)

It also looks like [FluorineFX](http://www.fluorinefx.com/) can communicate with an RTMP server. Not sure about playback but SharedObjects and their ilk can be accessed from .net.